# rails server bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried a number of things like uninstalling/reinstalling rails and gems but to no avail.

When I go into my new project and run rails s or bundle exec rails server I'm getting this error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/toabui/Sites/cms/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

Inside my bin/rails I see this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting that error when I run rails s?

I've googled and it seems like there is an error with the spring gem but I can‛t seem to get it to work.

Comment: I had this problem and the cause is configuration on the `database.yml` was different of adapter in `Gemfile`.

Comment: Actually i am also getting this error when i am using bulkmail gem.if I comment this gem then error is not coming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35851557/3728916 solved my issue

Answer (score 116):

I couldn't find the an_initilizer.rb in my directory and I tried uninstalling/installing the spring gem but it didn't work.

However I did managed to finally get it working.

Apparently there is some conflict with spring and rails 4+.

I needed to run:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

But I ran across another error:

```
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I ran the following command which I found on another stackoverflow post:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Then ran the original command:

```
 rake rails:update:bin
```

Then run the server command:

```
 rails s
```

And now my WebBrick Server is running.

Comment: Perfect, I also had to run
    `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: Might as well accept this answer; it seems to work for a lot of people.

Comment: It seems to be related to mysql, if you include mysql2 in your gemfile. this error will get raised whether you use mysql2 as the database or not.

Comment: I had the same errors. This fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant! Absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 40):

`rake rails:update:bin` to the rescue.

Answer (score 13):

If you are on El Capitan (OS X 10.11), Security Integrity Protection (SIP) will prevent linking into /usr/lib to fix mysql.  Link it into /usr/local/lib instead:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Comment: I get the error ln: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: File exists .. Any ideas?

Comment: @IsaacY what about -f option ?

Comment: If you installed mysql using homebrew or other method you can find out the libraries path by running `mysql_config --libs` then you do `sudo ln -s mypath /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

Answer (score 6):

This is work for me.

`gem uninstall mysql2`

`bundle install` or `gem install mysql2`

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error. Removed spring from Gemfile and re-bundled. Not really a solution though.

I found the code that created this error in `config/initializers/an_initializer.rb`

```
require "lib/a_file_i_need"
```

I changed it for

```
require "#{ Rails.root }/lib/a_file_i_need"
```

Comment: appending `#{Rails.root}` to the path helped me got rid of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error by trying to update rails 4 and imagemagick and rmagick. 
So I just ran

> gem uninstall rmagick

Select the All Versions option. Then try again

EDIT: This happaned again with me just now because I tried to use a gem without installing the required base gem. In my case the solution was to install 'omniauth-google' before trying to use 'omniauth-google-oauth2', but because I didn't install I got the same error again

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. I had ruby 2.1.3 and rails 4.1.6 running on Mavericks and then I migrated to Yosemite and installed the 4.2.0 rails version an ruby 2.1.5 and my apps I made in the previous version didn't work with the new one, so I made some gem sets with RVM and installed the 2.1.3 version.
Now when I wanted to run the server I got these error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/Lexynux/_WebProjects/RoR_Apps/SAIIP2/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

And as tobu mentioned I ran:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

I got this:

```
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/Lexynux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@SAIIP2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Then I ran this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

And finally I repeated the first command it the terminal asked me for this:

```
Overwrite /Users/Lexynux/_WebProjects/RoR_Apps/SAIIP2/bin/rails? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

I just typed 'Y' and hit return.

After all this I started working and going well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I received this error after upgrading postgresql.

```
$ gem uninstall pg
$ gem install pg
```

resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after doing a `brew upgrade`. My guess is that this broke some gems with native extensions, even though there was no error message pointing to that.

What I ended up doing was completely removing my installed gems (In my case I completely uninstalled and reinstalled the ruby version using `rbenv`).
Running `bundle install` recompiled the native extensions, and everything was running again.

Comment: In my case it was after upgrading mysql, so I only gem I had to uninstall was `mysql gem` and then run a bundle install.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post what worked for me.

Comment out

```
gem 'spring'
```

Add `gem 'net-shh'`

and run `bundle install`

And restart your sever

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, it happend to be related to `gem dotenv`.
Instructions were to add the following to Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
```

But as it turned out, `dotenv/rails-now` caused the error. If you use `dotenv` don't require `rails-now`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using pg and mysql in different branches ? If yes, please confirm db config file.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error after upgrading rails. Disabling `spring` give me a hint that the issue was with:

`gem 'google-api-client', require: 'google/api_client'`

Changed to:

`gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'`

Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message output when trying to start an application within a Vagrant environment. It cropped up out of nowhere after zero changes to the application code (and other weird behaviour followed, such as development.rb being deleted upon attempting to run the app).

In the end I simply halted the VM & restarted it, everything was then fine so I'm assuming it was an issue with file syncing / shared folders perhaps? (default Vagrant shared folder being used).

Answer (score 0):

Run these in console:

```
rake tmp:clear
rake secret
```

Answer (score 0):

#### IF `rake rails:update:bin` gives additional errors:

I had recently been doing some server maintenance and had subsequently updated OpenSSL.

When I tried running the `rake rails:update:bin` command, I was presented with an error relating to openSSL.

Having rebuilt my version of Ruby (`rvm reinstall ruby-x.x.x' with RVM), both errors went away.

This is always worth a try I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was using an outdated version of ruby 1.9.3 with rails 4.2. I upgraded to 2.1.2 , removed the broken project, ran rails new blog to recreate my project, navigated into my newly created app and ran rails server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found that it was being caused by the fact that I had removed a gem from the gemfile without deleting the other `require` references. In my case, I just had to remove it from config/application.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error recently, it is caused by spring, because of its suggested code in executables:

```
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
```

It originally expects a `LoadError` for spring itself in production, but by this code all other load error will be ignored too.

Thus if you have any other `LoadError` in rails loading process (for example in routes/init) spring worker startup fails and then there goes branch that tries to load everything again like there was no spring.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue presented as a result of bundle upgrading rvm-capistrano amongst other things.
Adding this require:false fixed things in the end as per this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461965/please-require-this-file-from-within-a-capistrano-recipe-loaderror)

```
gem  'rvm-capistrano',  require: false
```

Although could possibly be an additional issue - as running `rake rails:update:bin` may have helped clear the initial issue.