# Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano 2 with Rails 3 project. Recently I rebuilt my gemset form scratch and now I receive error "Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)" when I try to run rails server.

Detailed error message:

```
/Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/leonidlukin/Sites/moscowshows/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance': Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/helpers/base.rb:16:in `rvm_with_capistrano'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/helpers/_cset.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano/selector.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.5.6/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/Sites/moscowshows/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@moscowshows/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/Sites/moscowshows/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /Users/leonidlukin/Sites/moscowshows/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Which file I should require from within a Capistrano recipe?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The problem is with rvm-capistrano.

Correct it in gemfile. **require: false**

```
 gem  'rvm-capistrano',  require: false
```

This should help

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works like a charm. But could you please explain a little bit what happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @huynhquancam seems like this problem reappeared after release of bundler 1.8.0.  Bundler fails to load rvm-capistrano. Hopefully It going to be fixed.

Comment: The piece of code that is failing is here https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L85

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Posted detailed question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101421/please-require-this-file-from-within-a-capistrano-recipe-erro-while-deploying

Comment: @AmitPatel seems like you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 13):

A better solution I found, instead of removing it, to just move *rvm-capistrano* before *capistrano*:

```
# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time I give an answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

But, what's strange, I've solved this problem also like that (in my Gemfile, just to comment main capistrano gem):

```
# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano', :group => :development
gem 'rvm-capistrano', :group => :development
```

Comment: That makes sense. Although you will have to uncomment for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile change this.

`gem  'rvm-capistrano',  require: false`

This will solve the problem without any headache.