# Already initialized constant APP PATH rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I got this error just after installing devise 3.4.0 gem in my application. When I input `rails s` in terminal, I get the error below..

```
[kmartin@localhost register]$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/kmartin/work/register/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails server bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP\_PATH error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402820/rails-server-bin-rails6-warning-already-initialized-constant-app-path-error)

Comment: @shivam i have checked that link and seems all solutions there dont work for for my error cant figure out why

Comment: what does `rake rails:update:bin` returns?

Comment: @shivam it overwrites the previous bin/rails file and when i run rails s its give me error of uninitialised constant Mart..Mart is my devise user i created...[kmartin@localhost register]$ rake rails:update:bin
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
    conflict  bin/rails
Overwrite /home/kmartin/work/register/bin/rails? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Y
       force  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
   identical  bin/setup

Comment: Try running `rails c` - you should get a more explicit error

Answer (score 0):

I actually just changed my devise gem from 3.1. to just gem 'devise' then bundle installed and my problem was solved...It seems the version of devise wasnt supported by rails 4.

Comment: If you think you own answer solved your problem, and it should have - then accept it.

Comment: @ArslanAli it did though u cant accept your own answer before 2 days ellapse