# Rails: already initialized constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
$ rails server
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/songhowon/job/onboardiq_app/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

I tried everything. I reinstalled `rbenv`, `ruby`, etc. Many peole had the same issue according to the following post, but it doesn't work for me.

[rails server bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402820/rails-server-bin-rails6-warning-already-initialized-constant-app-path-error)

A strange thing is this error only occurs in a specific app. In a newly created app, `rails s` works great. I'd appreciate any help for this problem.

Comment: did you try disabling spring?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting into `bin/rails`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
  # need to investigate this error
  # but in production it will happen, so cannot just raise everytime
  raise if defined?(Rails) and Rails.env.development?
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```