# Rails already initialized constant HELP_MAPPINGS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, warnings, mappings

I am working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample app and I don't understand how I can fix the warning and the multiple tests that get run every time but don't do anything.

[Screenshot of multiple tests running with the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLNrI.png). 
I am unsure if this is messing with performance or if it something I should just ignore, but I would like to resolve this issue if possible.

Thanks for the help, friends!

Comment: Not sure but you may try to reinstall bundler with the same version that's shown in your Gemfile.lock.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851005/rails-server-bin-rails6-warning-already-initialized-constant-app-path-error/35851557#35851557) may help.

Comment: It did not work when I followed the link or when I uninstalled and reinstalled the bundler. Still getting the same warning with multiple tests getting run.

Comment: I think I've seen this happen somewhere where both `.rspec` contained a `--require rails_helper` and the spec itself was also `require`-ing that file.

Comment: I have the same problem since the new rails and jruby version (Rails 5.1.4). It is a great Question, but I would not worry to much. It seems like an "error" which is not caused by you, so better concentrate on your tuorial. Seems to be a problem with [minitest-reporter](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/issues/230)