# Cannot start the server with gem acts_as_xlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot start the server after adding the gem "acts as xlsx" to my gemfile.

I have read other posts on this problem but still haven't got a clue what is going on.   Most seem to have resolved the problem by removing the gem from the gemfile.   If I remove the gem, I can start the server but I need it to do what I want to do.  Also, I get the same message if I use the gem "axlsx" or "axlsx_rails", so I believe that something that is required in this gem is creating this issue.

The error message is

```
"bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH /home/ubuntu/workspace/horsestud_app/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Error: Command '-b' not recognized"
```

Thanking you in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that this is an issue with the gem? Does removing the gem fix the issue?

Comment: Do the instructions in [rails server bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402820/rails-server-bin-rails6-warning-already-initialized-constant-app-path-error) help at all?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you both for your questions.  1.   Removing the gem does fix the issue, and 2. I have researched the warning - "already initialized constant APP_Path...." and it does seem that most have to do with a gem causing the issue and removal of the gem resolves it.      Not a good solution, I would think, if you need or want the gem!    Would love to resolve this!

Comment: Note:   Also fails at a lower level with just the axlsx gem in the gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I got from posting this as well on axlsx_rails/issues.

"

You've ended up with axlsx 1.3.6 because you added acts_as_xlsx first. You'll want at least this in your Gemfile:

gem 'rubyzip', '= 1.0.0'
gem 'axlsx', '= 2.0.1'
gem 'axlsx_rails'

You could also use the github repo for axlsx. Another zip option is gem 'zip-zip'.

The acts_as_xlsx gem is not compatible with Rails 4 or above (if I remember correctly.) You'll want to use my version of the acts_ax_xlsx repo: https://github.com/straydogstudio/acts_as_xlsx.

Let me know how it goes."

This worked for me.    Thanks again straydogstudio!