# Issue during rails server initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to initialize my rails server I face below issue.
I'm using Ruby 2.1.8 and rails 4.2.5.1

```
bin/rails:8: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/venkata/eg/eg/bin/rails:8: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Error: Command '-p' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]**

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

Comment: Have a look at the answers in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402820/rails-server-bin-rails6-warning-already-initialized-constant-app-path-error